# float a series of fixed width divs with one expanding div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML. The child divs are all fixed width apart from the Suggestions div. What I want to happen is that when the gridrow div is expanded the **suggestions** tab also expands to fill up the space.

This is the kind of thing I've been trying so far but to no avail:

```css
.gridrow div:nth-child(2){
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(3){
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(4){
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(5){
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(6){
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridrow">
  <div class="gridheader">Suggestions</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Likes</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Submitted By</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Date</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Status</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Updated</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) instead of `float`

```css
.gridrow {
  display: flex;
}

.gridrow .gridheader {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gridrow .gridheader:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridrow">
  <div class="gridheader">Suggestions</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Likes</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Submitted By</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Date</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Status</div>
  <div class="gridheader">Updated</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hairmazing!! thanks. I'll accept in a few minutes when the site allows me

Comment: You're welcome. Just for clarification with `flex: 1;` `suggestions (or first-child in this case)` div will take rest of free `width`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below code it may help you

```css
.gridrow {
  display: flex;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(2){
   width: 40px;
}

.gridrow div:nth-child(1){
   width: auto;
}

.gridheader{
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridrow">
    <div class="gridheader">Suggestions</div>
    <div class="gridheader">Likes</div>
    <div class="gridheader">Submitted By</div>
    <div class="gridheader">Date</div>
    <div class="gridheader">Status</div>
    <div class="gridheader">Updated</div>
</div>
```